# How to Make Consecutive Numbers from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I have an array like this

```
[-2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,21]
```

Is anyone know, how to make the output from that array become integer like this

```
-2,4-8,10-11,15-18,21
```

The output will take the consecutive number become one number

This things is new for me, any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why some of the elements are not included?

Comment: all elements are included, as you see, the number from 4 until 8 is consecutive. So it become 4-8, I still figuring out how to solve this, but your help will be appreciated

Comment: you need to compute values ? (`15-18` = `-3`)

Comment: @theDreamer911 You want to remove the element in between 4 and 8? `4-8` this i will return `-4` because it will subtract the numbers

Comment: Do you want to implement Sorting?

Comment: @MaheerAli oh my fault, you right if the output is array 4-8 will become -4. Did you know, how to make it string/integer

Comment: @Jack it can be a sorting algorithm, but the array had been sorted from the beginning, I just wan to make all the consecutive elements become one value like 15,16,17,18 become 15-18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I created function for replacing a sequence in an array with a string containing its range. There are three functions.

`getConsectiveCount` will take array and index as arguments and will get the count of consecutive numbers after that.

`replaceFirstConsective` will take array and will replace only first sequence in the array.

`replaceAllConsectives` will replace all the sequences in an array.

```js
const arr = [-2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,21];
const getConsectiveCount = (arr, index) => {
  let count = 0;
  for(let i = index; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i + 1] === arr[index] + (i - index) + 1){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(getConsectiveCount(arr, 1));
const replaceFirstConsective = (arr) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let count = getConsectiveCount(arr,i);
    if(count){
      
  return [...arr.slice(0, i), `${arr[i]}-${arr[i + count]}`, ...arr.slice(i + count + 1)]
    }
  }
  return arr;
  
}
const replaceAllConsectives = (arr) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
    arr = replaceFirstConsective(arr)
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(replaceAllConsectives(arr)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const inp = [-2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,21];
let res = [];
for(let i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
        let b = inp[i];
    let j = i+1;
    while(j<inp.length){
        if(b+1 == inp[j]){
        b = inp[j++];
        continue;
      }
      break;
    }
    if(i == j-1){
     res.push(inp[i]);
     }
    else{
      res.push(inp[i]+"-"+inp[j-1]);
      i=j-1;
    } 
}
console.log(res);
```

Check this if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have done that :

```js
const arr1 = [-2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,21]

const arr2 = arr1.reduce((a,c,i,{[i+1]:nxt})=>
  {
  if (!a.s1) a.s1 = c.toString(10)
  if ( (c+1) !== nxt ) 
    {
    a.s1 += a.s2 ? `_${a.s2}` : ''
    a.r.push(a.s1)
    a.s1 = a.s2 = ''
    }
  else  a.s2 = nxt.toString(10)
 
  return (nxt===undefined) ? a.r : a
  },{r:[],s1:'',s2:''})


console.log(JSON.stringify( arr2 ))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting problem. The way I solved it was to iterate over the array and then find the index of the last consecutive number from the current one. We can either write the single number into the result array or write the range string in there and continue from the next number after the range.

```
function lastConsecutive(arr, start)
{    
    let ind = start;
    while(ind < arr.length && (arr[ind] + 1) == arr[ind + 1])
    {
        ind++;
    }

    return ind;
}

function consecCollapse(nums)
{
    let i = 0;
    const result = [];
    while (i < nums.length)
    {        
        let n = lastConsecutive(nums, i);
        result.push((n == i) ? nums[n]+"" : nums[i]+"-"+nums[n]);
        i = n + 1;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(consecCollapse([-2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,21]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [-2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,21];
const _newArray = [];
let start = arr[0];
let end = start;
for(let i=1; i<=arr.length; i++) {
    let elem = arr[i];
    if (elem === end+1) {
        end = elem; // update the end value (range)
    }else {
        if (end !== start) {
            _newArray.push(`${start}-${end}`);
        } else {
            _newArray.push(start);
        }
        start = elem;
        end = start;
    }
}

console.log(_newArray.join(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

If a sorted array with unique numbers, this is how I find the range of numbers with dash:

```js
function findRange(arr) {
    const results = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // only more than 2 consecutive numbers can be form a range
        if (arr[i + 1] === arr[i] + 1 && arr[i + 2] === arr[i] + 2) {
            // store the first number of a range
            results.push(arr[i])
            // loop until meet the next one is not consecutive
            while (arr[i] + 1 === arr[i + 1]) {
              i++
            }
            // store the last number of a range with '-' in between
            results[results.length - 1] = results[results.length - 1] + '-' + arr[i]
        } else {
            // if only 2 consecutive number or not consecutive at all
            results.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return results
}

console.log(findRange([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
console.log(findRange([1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
console.log(findRange([-2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15,16,17,18,21]))
```